# validation: exists in field OR in:0,NULL

Tags: laravel-4

I'm going to get field data that exists in database or be in a range.
is it possible to check input validation, that concurrent (exists in field database) OR (in:0,NULL)

Comment: create a custom validation rule based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121417/laravel-validation-exists-with-additional-column-condition-custom-validation/26122468#26122468

Comment: Thank you Jarek Tkaczyk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should determine custom validator like this:

```
public function validateCustomExists($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if ($value == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return $this->validateExists($attribute, $value, $parameters);
}
```

and in model validation:

```
    $this->rules = array(
        'field_id' => 'custom_exists:tableName,fieldName',
    );
```