# model should not exist with same make model laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel

In my project I want use validator to check already exist. Works fine for single existence. But in model add I want to check the same model should not exist with same type and make.with diff make or type it will be ok but not with same.

```
$input['name'] = Input::get('name');
$rules = array('name' => "unique:types,name");
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return Redirect::back()->with('alert-danger',"Type Name already exist.")->withInput();
} else {
    $type = new Type();
    $type_detail = $type->add_type($request);
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    return redirect('/types')->with('alert-success', 'Type Created successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give some more information?

Comment: please give clarity that what you need to check .

Comment: OK. You may achieve this using CustomValidation rules. Please check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121417/laravel-validation-exists-with-additional-column-condition-custom-validation

Comment: ex:   in city table we add adding state and country .now I want to validate that if the city is entered with already existed city and  state and country in city table it should show an error for city already exists.ex i had city records like city-pune,maharastra,india and then i add same city with same record should show an error but allo if i am adding with pune,gujrat,india.   i want rule validation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `$data` is as:

```
$input = [
    'city' => 'pune'
    'state' => 'maharastra'
    'country' => 'india'
]
```

Then your rules string should be as:

```
'city' => "unique:table_name,city,NULL,id,state,{$input['state']},country,{$input['state']}",
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: Thanks workng for store , but when i add $id at last for update validator  gives an error Please help.

Comment: Didn't get you. What is `$id` here?

Comment: ok forget it what will be changes if i want to use this in the update method

Comment: Replace `NULL` with your `$id` then it will work for the update.