# How can I validate a data that exists in data base or not with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to check data exist in mysql column if already exist show error message and not exist insert input data with laravel 5.2 Validator exists(database)
There's **my Code**.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, array('CardKeyCode' => 'exists:customer,CARDNO'));
if ($validator->passes()) {
      $ok = CustomerMaster::insert($input);
} else {
     return redirect('CustomerMaster/New')->withErrors("CardNo Already Exist!!");
}
```

Thanks!!! :D

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121417/laravel-validation-exists-with-additional-column-condition-custom-validation

Comment: How to make condition.That condition statement is not work.