# Declare a variable to be used in all methods Laravel

Tags: laravel

What is the best way to declare a variable to be used in all the methods within my controllers and my models:

example .. I want to replace:
Auth::user()
by:
$this->user

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: I definitely don't suggest doing this. It adds unnecessary logic - especially considering you can use the super globals

Comment: please can u help me in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249476/laravel-5-5-validation-message

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.3.4+

Declare the property in your controller and then you can do it like this in its `__construct` method:

```
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

For versions below, you can just `$this->user = Auth::user();` inside `__construct`.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to set a user in your `Controller.php`'s `__construct` method you will find it **won't work**.

**This won't work:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = auth()->check() ? auth()->user() : null;
}
```

This is by design, according Taylor, the framework's creator. He discourages setting your user in the base controller - but, it's up to you how you want to do things. There is a way around this. If you wanted `$this->user` to be accessible in every controller, you would add this to your `Controller.php` file:

```
protected function setUser()
{
    $this->user = auth()->check() ? auth()->user() : null;
}
```

Then in your `__construct` method call it:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setUser();
}
```

Now, you can access `this->user` from any controller method. It will be `null` if not set, but if you are using Laravel's standard auth guard you shouldn't have much of a problem with unauthenticated users getting through.